# smarty tag within a smarty tag

Tags: smarty, cmsmadesimple

hi im dealing with the CTLModuleMaker in , i have this

```
 {cms_module module="image_mod_test" what="image" where_project="{$item->id}" orderby="priority,id" template="inner_galleries"}
```

notice the **{$item->id}** for **where_project**, that thing doesn't work i basically want the id of the currently iterating object to show up in place of **{$item->id}**. i think it doesn't want to accept a smarty tag within a smarty tag,

any ideas what i should do,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Embedding Vars in Double Quotes**
>
> - Smarty will recognize assigned variables embedded in "double quotes"
>     so long as the variable name contains
>     only numbers, letters and
>     under_scores. See naming for more
>     detail.
> - With any other characters, for example a period(.) or
>     $object->reference, then the variable
>     must be surrounded by `backticks`.

[Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl)

So try this:

```
{cms_module module="image_mod_test" what="image" where_project="`$item->id`" orderby="priority,id" template="inner_galleries"}
```